# How can i make a this "vertical crop image" with canvas or css?

Tags: html, canvas, css

I have seen in some top-page sections of some sites a css effect in the top of the same section like a "horizontal-vertical-crop" which are done with some css (border-color & border-stile).

But how i can do the same with a background image instead color? 
(Explanation better in the image below)

[Explanation](http://imageshack.com/a/img839/5448/jg9k.jpg)

Original site link: [here](http://parasponsive.com/html5/)

Can i do it with canvas or css? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Yes, can be done in both canvas and CSS--probably easier in CSS.   What you have are people images underneath plus angled .pngs on top.  When the user scrolls, the background images are scrolled at a different rate than the forground angled pngs.  The result is the parallax reveal that you see.  Google parallax, reveal and scrolling -- there are many examples.

Comment: Hi markE, i don´t want how to learn to do parallax, i want to do put a background image (a pattern for example)at the top section of the div like i putted in the image example...ty!

Comment: Ok, I posted an answer showing how you can use canvas to clip any image you need into any shape that you need.  You can also use context.createPattern to do a clipped fill pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the html canvas to clip a rectangular image into the trapezoid shape you need:

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Mnkz3/

[image]
[image]

Then use canvas.toDataURL() to create an img element that you can position on your webpage.

```
// create a temporary canvas we can use to 
// make the clipped image
var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var img=new Image();
img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/city-q-c-640-480-2.jpg";
function start(){
    var w=canvas.width=img.width;
    var h=canvas.height=img.height;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.moveTo(0,100);
    ctx.lineTo(w,70);
    ctx.lineTo(w,h);
    ctx.lineTo(0,h-30);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    ctx.restore();

    var newImg=document.createElement("img");
    newImg.src=canvas.toDataURL();
    document.body.appendChild(newImg);
}
```

Alternatively, you can fill the clipping region with a repeating pattern like this:

```
var p=ctx.createPattern(img,"repeat");
ctx.fillStyle=p;
ctx.fill();
```

Comment: If i have a div with seamless pattern...how can i only clip the borders? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your clipping path can be any path you require!  Clipping your seamless pattern only on the resulting borders would not be difficult.  First, comment-out the ctx.clip and add ctx.stroke.  That way you'll see the full image and the stroked region that will become your clipping region. Then use multiple ctx.lineTo commands to "outline" your borders.  After outlining, remove ctx.stroke and uncomment ctx.clip.  Done!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure css solution you can use but I would strongly reccomend the use of an [**`SVG`**](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/) (
Scalable Vector Graphic).

To make the triangles responsive with css I made the `border-right` a high number to ensure it goes for large computers, a media query can help on small sizes. This is why an `SVG` would be better since it will be responsive when set to 100% width.

Here is the html:

```
<div class="triAngl">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the css:

```
.triAngl, .inner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -150px;
    background: #ff9900;
}

.triAngl:before, .triAngl:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    border-right: 0 solid transparent;
    border-left: 2000px solid transparent;
}

.triAngl:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    border-bottom: 50px solid #ff9900;
}

.triAngl:after {
    top: 100%;
    border-top: 50px solid #ff9900;
}

.inner {
    background: #2b2b2b;
}
```

Finally, a fiddle: [Demo, remove "show" in url to view code.](http://jsfiddle.net/2hwrP/1/show/)

Comment: Thanks for ur quick response Josh!
I mean this http://imageshack.com/a/img547/5681/d6g0.jpg